# Adding a specific pattern,if needed, in every line of a text file linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I have file with  the following format (the spaces is one tab)

```
sentenceA1      sentencek1
        sentencek2
        sentencek3
sentenceA2      sentencel1
        sentencel2
```

and I want the output to be:

```
sentenceA1      sentencek1
sentenceA1      sentencek2
sentenceA1      sentencek3
sentenceA2      sentencel1
sentenceA2      sentencel2
```

I tried separating the values by creating two files(using sed) one with the first and one with the second values but I don't know how to merge them afterwards successfully
Is this possible by only using sed or awk?

Answer (score 3):

This awk should work:

```
awk 'NF==2{p=$1; print; next} {print p, $1}' file
A1 k1
A1 k2
A1 k3
A2 l1
A2 l2
```

Comment: the problem is that A1, A2, k1 etc might be more than one word,
the separation though between the two values is always two spaces

Comment: You should specify that by editing your question and providing a more realistic example data.

Comment: give the real time data

Comment: @Nick: If field separator is **exactly 2 spaces** then use: `awk -F '  ' 'NF==2{p=$1; print; next} {print p, $0}' file`

Comment: I now realised that they are tab seperated. Sorry for the inconvenience but can you fix it for tab separation.?

Comment: i tried awk -F '\t ' 'NF==2{p=$1; print; next} {print p, $0}' file
and also without the NF but it does not work

Comment: That should work, just provide a sample data for which it doesn't work in your question and I will investigate and suggest an alternative.

Comment: it is a simple mistake. in the second print it should be $2! So the working code is the following:
-F '\t ' 'NF==2{p=$1; print; next} {print p, $2}' file

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/^\t/{p=substr($0,1,index($0,"\t"))} /^\t/{$0=p$0}1' input
```

Comment: This works, but ads an extra `tab`, remove it by `-1` in the index.  You do not also need to do the same test twice: `awk '{/^\t/?$0=p$0:p=substr($0,1,index($0,"\t")-1)}1'`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a rewritten `awk` based on anubhavas post to get the data correct.

```
awk -F"\t" '$1{p=$1;print;next} {print p$0}' file
sentenceA1      sentencek1
sentenceA1      sentencek2
sentenceA1      sentencek3
sentenceA2      sentencel1
sentenceA2      sentencel2
```

Since there are `tabs` in all line, all line will have same numbers of fields.
If line starts with `tab`, first field will be nothing, so `$1` will test for this.